# "switch to" history is not working in ankhsvn

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ankhsvn

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and AnkhSvn. There's a panel called `PendingChanges` (it's main panel). I use it to switch to different branches. There is a combo-box with path to current branch and "Other..." entry. I think when I switch to different branch it supposed to remember path to previously loaded branch so I can quickly switch back. But it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong? Or maybe there is a setting to do that? Is there a quick way to switch between different branches?

P.S. Don't know whether this question is for SO. If not, delete please.

Comment: Seems like the perfect question to ask at the AnkhSVN mailing list / forum, which I saw you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. The drop down doesn't show recent branches (yet).

Comment: When will it show recent branches? Typing the branch URL every time (or waiting for the explorer to load) is really annoying.

Comment: Yes, annoying!!